# GraphQL error: access denied for Orders on Shopify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, graphql, shopify

I got this error to fetch orders with '@shopify/koa-shopify-auth'.

[GraphQL error: access denied]

The query is like this.

```
query {
  orders(first:2) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I set below scopes.

```
  server.use(
    createShopifyAuth({
      apiKey: SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
      secret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
      scopes: [
        'read_products','write_products',
        'read_orders', 'write_orders', 'read_all_orders',
        'read_script_tags', 'write_script_tags'
      ],
      afterAuth(ctx) {
        const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.session;
        ctx.cookies.set('shopOrigin', shop, {
          httpOnly: false,
          secure: true,
          sameSite: 'none'
        });
        ctx.redirect('/');
      },
    }),
  );
```

Whereas I could get product info. In addition, I could get order information via GraphiQL App.

I researched the problem, I couldn't get any clues. Do you have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the reasons.

1st-
I have to add `reverse: true` into GraphQl like below.

```
  orders(first: 2 reverse: true) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2nd -
I needed to restart and update app after adding `'read_orders', 'write_orders'`permmissions.

Thanks!